Problems running code in an Excel worksheet embedded in Ms OneNote
I have a OneNote note that has an embedded Excel spreadsheet. The worksheet has code that is run by formulae in the worksheet. It works fine if the worksheet is opened from Excel, but if I run it when embedded in OneNote, I get '?NAME' errors.
I have looked at permissions in Excel, but nothing seems to cure the problem.
In more detail:
I have a spreadsheet for astrophotography that calculates the Altitude and Azimuth of a star (the position in the sky as viewed from a specific location) from the RA/Dec astronomical position and the time of day. I wrote an Excel vba function to do the calculations.
I then insert the function into a cell in the worksheet and it displays a table of positions against time. It works well, from Excel, but as soon as I embed the sheet in a OneNote note, select edit, then recalculate the sheet, I get '?NAME' errors in all the cells that contain the function.
I guess it's related to permissions, but I can't figure out the solution.
I set macro permissions in Excel to accept code from my local disk, but that didn't help.
Has anyone got any ideas? I can post an example sheet, if that helps?
Pete
Screenshots:
Before:

After:


I tried it by embedding the Excel WB into a Word document, and tried several updates with success. I don't know why it does not work with OneNote. Sample file:https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1tQKdEuIfhIkvFyZUcmuT6KtwjpdoYty_

I have created an Excel .xlsm with a simple function in it and inserted it into a OneNote page - I get a menu with Attach File / Insert Spreadsheet / Insert a Chart or Table so I select Insert Spreadsheet. The I select Edit from wiithin OneNote and a spreadsheet opens and the function appears to work. The workbook opened is called xl_Azimuth1.xlsm which is not the name I inserted. I can not find the actual file xl_Azimuth1.xlsm. The workbook file is not the original and it is not where you expect it to be! Please post your code and maybe we can help you.

@MT1 - I think you need to use "Attach Spreadsheet" otherwise you just get a copy of the file...

Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/OneNote/comments/1d5peaf/having_an_embedded_excel_spreadsheet_in_company/

The macro is blocked as described here
